# Ruby on Rails: No Route Matches Error when Route Exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hyperlink, routes

I am trying to link to an incredibly simple series of `welcome#___` type pages and keep getting `No route matches [GET] ...` errors.

The three links I am trying are:

```
<%= link_to 'welcome_personality_path' do %>
   ...
<% end %>
```

and

```
<%= link_to 'welcome_game_path' do %>
   ...
<% end %>
```

and

```
<%= link_to 'welcome_body_path' do %>
   ...
<% end %>
```

I get the `no route matches` errors for each one even though my rake routes show that these routes exist:

```
      welcome_index GET    /welcome/index(.:format)         welcome#index
welcome_personality GET    /welcome/personality(.:format)   welcome#personality
       welcome_game GET    /welcome/game(.:format)          welcome#game
       welcome_body GET    /welcome/body(.:format)          welcome#body
  welcome_resources GET    /welcome/resources(.:format)     welcome#resources
      welcome_about GET    /welcome/about(.:format)         welcome#about
```

This seems an incredibly simple thing to be getting an error message on, so I'm perplexed.  None of these pages take any parameters or require special permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove quotes around your paths (`welcome_personality_path`, not `"welcome_personality_path"`):

```
<%= link_to welcome_personality_path do %>
   ...
<% end %>
```

Comment: Aaaah!  I knew it was something moronically simple.  Thank you!

Comment: Just a reminder, the `link_to` helper actually receives a string parameter. Note that `welcome_personality_path` is a method call that returns a string containing the path you want.